# How not to "naturalize" surrogate keys?

Tags: primary-key, surrogate-key, web-service

> Don't naturalize surrogate keys. As soon as you display the value of a surrogate key to your end users, or worse yet allow them to work with the value (perhaps to search), you have effectively given the key business meaning. This in effect naturalizes the key and thereby negates some of the advantages of surrogate keys.
>
> http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html

> Don’t “naturalize” surrogate keys. As soon as you display the value of a surrogate key to your end users, or worse yet allow users to work with the value (perhaps via search), you have effectively given the key business meaning. The exposed key in our database could then be considered a natural key in someone else’s.
>
> https://begriffs.com/posts/2018-01-01-sql-keys-in-depth.html

And yet, every web framework/ORM I am familiar with (e.g. Ruby on Rails) exposes the surrogate key in the URL which is natural key that users share, send, save, bookmark, etc.

In light this of this recommendation, what are the best practices for handling web URLs?

Comment: This isn't really a database design problem; it's an application design problem. If the framework you use forces you to expose surrogate keys, and you don't want that, choose another framework. Personally, I don't see that as such a big deal. It's an opinion of one person on the internet, shared, or at least quoted, by a handful of others, not a dogma.